# Python: Evaluate the output of my functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a large dataframe with many columns however I am only looking at one column in particular.

This example is for simplicity. I have defined a new column, col2, that will store a Boolean if the conditions in the first column are met.

```
raw_data = { 'col1': [[0, 2, 3, 4],[6, 7, 1000, 40, 20],[4, 20, 100]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['col1'])
df

df['col2'] = 'default'
df

                     col1                   col2
row1         [2,3,44,89.6,...]            default
row2         [10,4,33.3,1.11,...]         default
```

I need to do some calculations on col1 and if some conditions are met, the default in col2 in that same row becomes True, False otherwise.

**Simplified calculations**

Calculate the maximum value in the list, the length of the list and the average value.

I do these calculations in a function and then I introduce another function that attempts to do the evaluation part.

For example, if the maximum value is > 10 and if length of the list is > 5 and if the average value is > 25, make that default value in col2 be True.

I believe that I have to use .apply() function.

```
df['col2'] = df.apply (lambda row: my_functions (row),axis=1)
```

**Required Output**

```
                   col1                   col2
row1         [2,3,44,89.6,...]            True
row2         [10,4,33.3,1.11,...]         False
```

I am quite stuck here as I do not know how to do some calculations and iterate over an entire column and evaluate those calculations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vectorized functions if you have a large dataframe:

```
def my_func(l):
    return (max(l) > 10) and (len(l) > 5) and (np.mean(l) > 25)

my_func = np.vectorize(my_func)

df['col2'] = my_func(df['col1'].values)
```

OUTPUT:

```
col1                        col2
[0, 2, 3, 4]                False
[6, 7, 1000, 40, 20, 13]    True
[4, 20, 100]                False
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but you don't need to set `col2` before doing the computation. You can put in a function of your choosing in the `apply` attribute. Just remember that the input to the function using `apply` is **row by row**.

```
raw_data = { 'col1': [[0, 2, 3, 4],[6, 7, 1000, 40, 20],[4, 20, 100]]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['col1'])

    # if max(list) > 10 --> True

def my_function (row):

    if max(row['col1'])>10:
        row = True
    else:
        row = False
    return row


df['col2'] = df.apply(my_function, axis =1)

df
                   col1   col2
0          [0, 2, 3, 4]  False
1  [6, 7, 1000, 40, 20]   True
2          [4, 20, 100]   True
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do:

```
raw_data = {'col1': [[0, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 1000, 40, 20, 13], [4, 20, 100]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['col1'])

def my_functions(r):
    nb = len(r.col1)
    average = sum(r.col1) / nb
    maxl = max(r.col1)
    return maxl > 10 and len(r.col1) > 5 and average > 25


df['col2'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_functions(row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

output:

```
                       col1   col2
0              [0, 2, 3, 4]  False
1  [6, 7, 1000, 40, 20, 13]   True
2              [4, 20, 100]  False
```